# Any good resources or guides for mobile web application design?

Tags: css, mobile, web-applications, mobile-website

I'm working on a pretty standard website for a client.  One of the requirements is a mobile version of the site which can be displayed nicely on smartphones and tablets.  This is new territory for me.  A Google search mostly turned up DIY products and services catered to business owners lacking development resources.

With that said, does anyone have a good guide or place to start?  I have a pretty good background with the LAMP stack, JS, jQuery, HTML, and CSS so it doesn't need to be an *absolute* beginner's guide.  Just some ideas, resources, frameworks, or plugins that could be useful.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.elated.com/articles/responsive-web-design-demystified/

Comment: Take a look at the http://www,lynda.com 's videos and http://teamtreehouse.com is another resource

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to go with bootstrap framework for your first mobile development project. The framework will be very straight for beginners. Good knowledge in HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery is sufficient to build a mobile site using jquery.

LINK: http://getbootstrap.com/

And also i love the blog "11 tips for developing a mobile app that users will love". Just have a look before you start development so that it will boost your UX thought process.

http://thenextweb.com/dd/2013/05/25/11-tips-for-developing-a-startup-mobile-app-users-love/